# AWS Data Pipeline - Error when trying to re-run a failed acitivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

My datapipeline has many acitivities (Shellcommandactivity) one of which has failed due to a programmatic issue. However when i try to re-run the failed activity after fixing programmatic issue. Failure & rerun mode is - cascade & schedule Type is On demand. I get the below error

The given input is not valid: Set status 'RERUN' is not allowed on finished objects Activity2 (ShellCommandActivityId_vGL6K) (Service: DataPipeline; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 9a0cd59b-6a02-11e6-8592-cbb9c966228d)

I have all access including administrator access. I have gone through all the posts and the documentation but was not able to find an answer

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens because the EDP is not in active status. When EDP is 'inactive' or its schedule is closed, you cannot rerun its steps anymore. I don't know how to schedule this kind of EDP again. A workaround is to clone the EDP and activate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try cloning the pipeline and activating it.

Comment: I need a pipeline that i can run in production. I cant clone the pipeline every time I have a failure. I need the ability to run it from point of failure.

Comment: If your job is always failing, you should add the underlying issue.

But I think you are referring to intermittent failures due to some transient issues, then you should have retries.  Data Pipeline activities retry up to 3 times by default.

Comment: I meant you should *fix* the underlying issue.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though  - how do you manually (not via automatic retry) run-run a failed pipeline? And it seems the answer is : you can't, which is a very odd limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one attempt to run activity or pipeline then you can run only once, to run multiple times follow below steps.
I have rerun pipeline by following below steps:
1. go to list pipeline 
2. click on pipleine and click on edit pipeline
3. go to Schedules
4. edit Occurrences make it 1 to 10.
5. save pipeline.
6. Activate pipeline.
7. rerun that task or activity.